# DB2 Connection with Pyspark local

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, pyspark, db2

I am trying to connect to db2 via pyspark, below is my connection string.

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext, SQLContext

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("test").setMaster("local").set("spark.jars","\IBM\IBM_DATA_SERVER_DRIVER\java\db2jcc4.jar")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)



df = (sqlContext.read.format('jdbc')\
      .option('url', 'jdbc:db2://********.COM:*****/*****')\
      .option('driver', 'com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver')\
      .option('dbtable', "(SELECT * FROM table.table limit 100) as t")\
      .option('user', 'user')\
      .option('password', 'password')).load()
```

However, I am getting an error as below

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o161.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.DriverRegistry$.register(DriverRegistry.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions$$anonfun$5.apply(JDBCOptions.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions$$anonfun$5.apply(JDBCOptions.scala:99)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.<init>(JDBCOptions.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.<init>(JDBCOptions.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:332)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:242)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:230)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:186)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I have downloaded latest driver and have it specified.
Could you help me resolve this issue to connect to db2 via pyspark.

Comment: When setting spark.jars , try the forward-slash as the directory separator instead of the backslash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not specifying the driver. Putting the jar file for db2 in `$SPARK_HOME/jars` should be enough.

Also use `SparkSession` to read input files. `SQLContext` is deprecated.